# Fortran : Initialize all variables to a specific default value

Tags: fortran, intel, fortran90, gfortran, pgi

I am working on a ~40 years old Fortran spaghetti code with lots of variables that are implicitly declared. So there is not a simple way to even know what variables exist in the code in order to initialize their values.  Now, is there a way to tell the compiler (for example Intel Fortran) to initialize all variables in the code to a specific default value (e.g., -999) other than zero or a very large number, as provided by Intel compiler?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`gfortran` provides some options for this. Integers can be intialized with `-finit-integer=n` where `n` is an integer. For real numbers you can use `-finit-real=<zero|inf|-inf|nan|snan>`. Together with `-ffpe-trap=denormal` this can be very helpful, to get uninitialized reals.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want :

```
 ifort -check uninit
```

Note per the man page this only checks scalars

Also, based on some quick testing it is a pretty weak check. It doesn't catch this simple thing for example:

```
 program test
 call f(i)
 end
 subroutine f(j)
 write(*,*)j
 end
```

returns `0` ..

I suppose its better than nothing though.

Comment: More info about the weakness of this check: https://www.nas.nasa.gov/hecc/assets/pdf/training/UnInit_Fix_your_code_2012_10_31.pdf